# How can I get "firebase deploy --only functions" command to use the package.json in the functions/ directory?

Tags: firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions, package.json, firebase-cli

I've got the standard app structure for a Firebase/Angular application.

```
- functions/
   |--- index.ts
   |--- package.json
- src/
   |--- app/
   |     |--- (angular stuff)
   |--- index.html
   |--- ...
- package.json
- firebase.json
```

The problem is that when I run `firebase deploy --only functions`, the predeploy hooks that I've defined in `firebase.json`, are called from inside the `root/` directory, and not from inside `root/functions/` directory.

So for example, in `root/package.json` I have

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "echo": "echo 'hello1'"
  },
...
}
```

but in **`root/functions/package.json`** I have

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "echo": "echo 'hello2'"
  },
...
}
```

and in my `firebase.json` file I have

```
{
  ...
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm run echo"
    ]
  },
```

No matter whether I am in `root/` or `root/functions`, when I run `firebase deploy --only functions` I get **`hello1`**

How do I configure my Firebase tools to use the configurations (i.e. namely the `package.json` stuff) from `functions/` when I run `deploy --only functions` ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the best way to get this working, according to [the Firebase Typescript docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript#using_an_existing_typescript_project), is to specify the `predeploy` hook as follows

```
{
   "functions": {
     "predeploy": "npm --prefix functions run build",
   }
 }
```

This calls `npm run build` from inside the `functions` directory, so it will call the `build` script in `functions/package.json` and not the project root's `package.json`